# Can't we use Instruments with a real-device attached, instead of using iOS simulator ??

Tags: xcode6, ios-simulator, xcode-instruments, ios8.3

- Am currently using Xcode6.4 , and I am actually trying out the Instruments (time profiler) for the first time...
- The Instrument is working fine if I choose simulator and somethig wierd is happenning when I connect to a real-device(iOSv8.3)...(i.e)the application hangs.

My question is that is there a way to use instruments  with a real device connected ??

Pls do share if u came across the same probs and found a solution ...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

[Here is Apple documentation that talks about it a bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/GatheringDatafortheFirstTime/GatheringDatafortheFirstTime.html).  Note this paragraph:

> In order to use Instruments to profile an iOS device, your
>   device must be provisioned for development before data can be
>   collected from it. See Provisioning Your iOS Device for Development.